# Getting 500 Internal Server Error while creating Eloqua form with multiple fields using Rest Api

Tags: eloqua

I have a requirement to support forms of [Oracle Eloqua Marketing Cloud Service](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-rest-1.0-assets-form-post.html) in my project. I was testing the rest api for forms. So when I create form with single field using the create endpoint form is created in Eloqua CMS. But when I try to create form with Muliple fields it throws 500 InternalServerError.

> **Endpoint**:
>   REST/2.0/assets/form
>
> **Request Body**:
>   {
>      "name":"ELA_Form",
>      "elements":[
>           {
>               "type": "FormField",
>               "name": "Address 1",
>               "style": "{\"fieldSize\":\"large\",\"labelPosition\":\"top\"}",
>               "createdFromContactFieldId": "100006",
>               "dataType": "text",
>               "displayType": "text",
>               "fieldMergeId": "36",
>               "htmlName": "address1",
>               "useGlobalSubscriptionStatus": "False",
>               "validations": []
>           },
>           {
>               "type": "FormField",
>               "name": "Address 2",
>               "style": "{\"fieldSize\":\"large\",\"labelPosition\":\"top\"}",
>               "createdFromContactFieldId": "100007",
>               "dataType": "text",
>               "displayType": "text",
>               "fieldMergeId": "37",
>               "htmlName": "address2",
>               "useGlobalSubscriptionStatus": "False",
>               "validations": []
>           }
>           ],
>     "processingType":"externalEmail"
>   }
>
> **Response**: 
>   Internal Server Error
>   There was an internal server error.
>   The error has been logged with log identifier 121363909.
>   Please provide this log identifier to technical support.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set unique negative integers for the id for each field. Here is an example with them added that will result in successfully creating the form:

```
POST /API/REST/2.0/assets/form
{
  "name": "ELA_Form",
  "elements": [
    {
      "type": "FormField",
      "id": "-1",
      "name": "Address 1",
      "style": "{\"fieldSize\":\"large\",\"labelPosition\":\"top\"}",
      "createdFromContactFieldId": "100006",
      "dataType": "text",
      "displayType": "text",
      "fieldMergeId": "36",
      "htmlName": "address1",
      "useGlobalSubscriptionStatus": "False",
      "validations": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "FormField",
      "id": "-2",
      "name": "Address 2",
      "style": "{\"fieldSize\":\"large\",\"labelPosition\":\"top\"}",
      "createdFromContactFieldId": "100007",
      "dataType": "text",
      "displayType": "text",
      "fieldMergeId": "37",
      "htmlName": "address2",
      "useGlobalSubscriptionStatus": "False",
      "validations": [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "processingType": "externalEmail"
}
```